# Changing the value of a variable in every iteration using python

Tags: python, for-loop

Suppose 
a=0
b=a+5
print b

I want to update the value of variable **a** five times. The initial value is zero. So for the next five iterations the value of **a** should be updated as: 10,25,50,75 and 100.

Comment: You knew enough to use the `for-loop` tag; what problems are you having writing a `for` loop in Python?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uuuh....

```py
data = [0, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100]

a = None
for i in data:
     a = i
     print(a)
```

outputs

```
0
10
25
50
75
100
```